Настройка check boxes
Вопрос может показаться глупым, но всё же. В чекбоксе, мне нужно создать зелёные и красные зоны, а как сделать их, я не могу понять. Вот пример как должно получаться: 
Что получилось у меня: 
Код:
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Subscribe
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked> Subscribe
</label>

Css:
input[type="checkbox"]{
appearance:none;
background:limegreen;
border:10px solid green;
width: 40px;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid;
}

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked{
      background:white;
      border-color:red;  
      }


Добавьте для вашего элемента "::before" и расположите его абсолютно - это и будет ваш квдратик.



label {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background: white;
  border-color: limegreen;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
  border-color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all 300ms;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked:after {
  background: limegreen;
  left: calc(100% - 1px);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Subscribe
</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Subscribe
</label>



